# Any benchmark data available for average wages,benefits based on job position and state wise?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some data that I need for benchmarking purpose. The fields that I am interested in are:

1. Average salary/wage
2. Average benefits (like average bonus etc.)

Apart from this I am also optionally looking for some stats regarding average training time and cost for new hires based on job position.

I am looking for data which has position(like software engineer,financial analyst,marketing manager and so on) and state wise data and which I can download.

I found [this](http://www.salary.com/category/salary/) website upon looking. It does have salary info and bonus info based on job positions and state wise but I don't find any way to download this data and I sure cannot do that manually as there are far too many positions.

Can anyone point to me where I can find such a data or if anyone knows how can I download the whole data from above website I mentioned?